# Variable length Fibonacci word

Tags: code-golf, string, sequence, fibonacci

## Challenge

For any two non-empty strings A and B, we define the following sequence :

```
F(0) = A
F(1) = B
F(n) = F(n-1) + F(n-2)
```

Where `+` denotates the standard string concatenation.

The sequence for strings "A" and "B" starts with the following terms: A, B, BA, BAB, BABBA, ...

Create a function or program that, when given two strings `A` and `B`, and a positive integer `I` returns the `I`-th character of `F(∞)`.

You may choose to use 0-indexing or 1-indexing for `I`, just specify it in your answer.

You may assume the strings contain only uppercase (or lowercase) letters.

This is a variation of [Project Euler's Problem 230](https://projecteuler.net/problem=230), where the two strings were strings of digits of equal length, which trivialize the problem.

## Input/Output

You may choose any format for the input. The output should only contain the desired character, with trailing spaces/newlines allowed.

## Test Cases

```
ABC, DEF, 1234567890 → A
ACBB, DEFGH, 45865 → B
A, B, 3 → B
ABC, DEF, 10 → E
```

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the lowest byte count for each language wins!

Comment: Could you provide a smaller test case, say `ABC`, `DEF`, 10?

Comment: Can we just output F(∞)?

Comment: @l4m2 F(∞) by definition has infinite length, so outputting it would take some time

Comment: Also, shouldn't it be `F(n) = F(n-1) + F(n-2)`?

Comment: @user typo, fixed

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing I added the test case, and the order is correct, the next term is (last term) + (penultimate term)

Comment: Is this possible in RegEx?

Comment: Are we ensured that both input strings are non-empty?

Comment: @LuisMendo yes, I'll add that to the post

Comment: @zdimension Can we just output the entire string `F(∞)`? You didn't really answer l4m2's question.

Comment: @user again, not sure what is meant by "output the entire string". If the problem were "output the nth digit of pi", I don't think "output the entire decimal representation of pi" would be an acceptable solution, since the program would not finish. Do you mean "output the string up to the nth character" ?

Comment: @zdimension In sequence challenges, you're usually allowed to output the nth element, all elements up to the nth element, or all elements. You're right that the program wouldn't finish, but I don't see how that matters, since it would eventually output any F(n).

Comment: @user that makes sense, I hadn't understood it that way. I guess outputting the string isn't an issue, as long as the required output (nth character) is easily seen

Answer (score 11):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 15 bytes

```hs
a#b=b++b#(a++b)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYxLCoJAHMb3nuLvYzGDYxRltNBAzWrRDURw1NGGxgcqdIMO0BE7SNMotPnge/3udHwwIaSkZu7ntp2biCrFsqG89ctOA0goyQknXeo5z24ox1XFxcQGlLXdFAvWZMbn9SYG9qxjzaYbb5k69QNvJytBCot1HQ2MlsBx6vszcWbLIApDAqf4fLkS2LmHvQuKA6EWEFDF9u/CaFkR2KyXKP4WlaD1KJ2i738)

Takes strings `a` and `b` as input, returns the whole infinite Fibonacci word, as is usually allowed in [sequence](/questions/tagged/sequence) challenges.

### How?

Not much to say. This answer relies on the identity
$$
F(a,b)=b+F(b,a+b),
$$
where \$F(a,b)\$ is the infinite Fibonacci word with starting words \$a\$ and \$b\$.

Comment: Just a reminder that marking something as non-competitive does not allow it to be invalid, so if it turns out that it isn't allowed to output `F(∞)`, then you should modify your answer :)

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing Duly noted :(

Answer (score 10):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>6</s> 5 bytes

```
⁹;¡⁵ị
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASQA2/9qZWxsef//4oG5O8Kh4oG14buL////IkFCQyL/IkRFRiL/MTA)

Uses 1 indexing

-1 byte thanks to [Jonathan Allan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/53748/jonathan-allan), noticing that we could avoid `⁵` becoming the right argument to `;¡` by forcing `;¡` into a nilad-dyad pair with `⁹`!

Dyadic `¡` is essentially Jelly's generalised Fibonacci operator

### How it works

```
⁹;¡⁵ị - Main link. Takes A on the left, B on the right and I as the third argument
⁹     - Set the return value to B
  ¡   - I times do the following, swapping the updated arguments each time:
 ;    -   Concatenate the arguments
   ⁵ị - Yield the i'th character of the result
```

When `;¡` is run with 2 arguments, it does the following (calling the initial left argument `B` and the initial right argument `A`, as `⁹` essentially "swaps" the order of the arguments. We'll do 3 iterations):

- Iteration 1: `;` concatenates `B` and `A`, yielding `BA`. We then move `B` to the right and take `BA` as our left argument for the next iteration
- Iteration 2: `;` concatenates `BA` and `B`, yielding `BAB`. Our arguments become `BAB` on the left and `BA` on the right
- Iteration 3: `;` concatenates `BAB` and `BA`, yielding `BABBA`. This is the last iteration, so we return `BABBA`

Comment: 5 bytes using a leading constant chain instead with `⁹;¡⁵ị` - [TIO](https://tio.run/##ASQA2/9qZWxsef//4oG5O8Kh4oG14buL////IkFCQyL/IkRFRiL/MTA).

Comment: @JonathanAllan That's a brilliant catch, thanks!

Comment: Now we need tribonacci version to make the `¡` unusable :P

Answer (score 9):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 36 bytes

```python
f=lambda a,b,i:b[i:i+1]or f(b,b+a,i)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P802JzE3KSVRIVEnSSfTKik60ypT2zA2v0ghTSNJJ0k7USdT839BUWZeiUaahpKjs5OTko6Ckourm7sHkGFiamFmqqn5HwA)

-8 bytes thanks to dingledooper

<s>Not a particularly creative approach. In fact, basically this is just what l4m2 did but Python will error when accessing out of bounds instead of returning `undefined`.</s> Using `b[i:i+1]` returns `b[i]` (for strings) if it's in range, but doesn't error and instead gives `""` if it's out of range. Thanks to dingledooper for that.

Go upvote [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/223326/68942) too. This isn't really intentionally a port because I thought of the same idea but it's an identical approach.

Comment: Does `f=lambda a,b,i:b[i:i+1]or f(b,b+a,i)` work for 36 bytes?

Comment: @dingledooper yes, that's clever. thanks!

Answer (score 7):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 26 bytes

```javascript
n=>g=a=>b=>b[n]||g(b)(b+a)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/P1i7dNtHWLgmIovNia2rSNZI0NZK0EzX/J@fnFefnpOrl5KdrpGkYa2qoO6oDCSd1TU0uVDlDA5CkkzNI2sXVDVOBiamFmSlIjbOTE1SRuwcWc4yMTUzNzC0sMcz7DwA)

Thank tsh for -1 Byte

Comment: This answer fails for the last string....

Comment: @Wasif Because of insufficant RAM

Comment: [`n=>g=a=>b=>b[n]||g(b)(b+a)`](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/P1i7dNtHWLgmIovNia2rSNZI0NZK0EzX/J@fnFefnpOrl5KdrpGkYa2qoO6oDCSd1TU0uVDlDA5CkkzNI2sXVDVOBiamFmSlIjbOTE1SRuwcWc4yMTUzNzC0sMcz7DwA)

Answer (score 5):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 5 bytes

A rip-off of [Delfad0r's beautiful Haskell answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/223332/95792). Go upvote that!

```
S+S₀+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/P1g7@FFTg/b///@VHJX@KzkpAQA)

Returns the entire infinite string/list.

`S+S₀+ a b` is `(S+) ((S₀) (+a)) b`, which expands to `(+b) ((S₀ (+a)) b)` (where `₀` is a self-reference to the main function) and then to `(+b) (₀ b (+a b))`, which is basically `b + F(b, a + b)`.

#### Safer answer, 8 bytes

```
!₁
S+S₁+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/X/FRUyNXsHYwkNL@//@/kqOTs9J/JRdXN6X/hoYA)

This one gets the Ith character, at the cost of 3 bytes.

Comment: The non-`fix` method is shorter here: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/X/Hc4kML8x@1TXq4q0v7////0UqOTs5KOkourm5Ksf8tAQ "Husk – Try It Online")

Comment: @Razetime ...wow. Do you want to post that as your own answer?

Comment: nah, feel free to modify.

Comment: @Razetime Alright, thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately both options seem to return 'A' for input 'ABC','DEF',1 while they should return 'D' instead. They are also not equivalent to each other for other inputs

Comment: @Leo I think I know why that is, let me fix it later

Comment: @Leo Fixed now (and a lot shorter!). I *think* it's correct, it sticks with the Haskell answer for the [first 80 characters](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P1E5yTZJWztJWSMRSGr@z03MzLNNyedSUCgoyswrUVBRKEnMTlWwMACylByVFJQVlJyUuLh0dRU8IEYoODk6ARGYgNEoHKyCeFSAzS4tzlYAAmqbTYK2/47OTk46Ci6ubu4eOgomphZmpgqP2iYpOHE56igAJYxhPCdnsCodBUMDsJArAA).

Comment: That's very nice! I was struggling to find a short solution for this... The only problem with both this and the Haskell answer is that the challenge does not explicitly allow printing the full sequence... I hope they'll change their mind, but at worst this would be fixable with just 2 or 3 extra bytes

Comment: @Leo Ah, you're right. I've added another version just in case.

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>6</s> 5 bytes

-1 byte by assuming the input words consist only of letters (`è` implicitly swaps arguments if the first one doesn't look like a number)

Takes inputs `[A, B]` and `n`.

```
λèì}è
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//3O7DKw6vqT284v//aCVHJ2clHQUlF1c3pVguQwMA)

**Commented**:

```
λè }    # get the nth element of the sequence generated by:
  ì     #   prepending the current string to the last string
        # that starts with [A, B]
     è  # index with n into the nth element of the sequence
```

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>96</s> <s>92</s> 84 bytes

```r
function(A,B,I,`!`=function(k)"if"(k,"if"(k>1,paste0(!k-1,!k-2),B),A))substr(!I,I,I)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/pfXFKUlplk@z@tNC@5JDM/T8NRx0nHUydBMcEWLpStqZSZpqSRrQOh7Ax1ChKLS1INNBSzdQ11gISRpo6Tpo6jpmZxaRLQQA1FT6ARnppQwzWUHJV0FJScgISxtqEmF1zUyRkk7uLqBqQMDYBS/wE)

Takes `I` 1-indexed.

*-8 bytes thanks to [@Dominic](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/95126/dominic-van-essen)*

Comment: At risk of outgolfing [my own attempt](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/223385/95126), I think you can save a few bytes using ```substr``` instead of ```strsplit```: [try it](https://tio.run/##K/pfXFKUlplk@z@tNC@5JDM/T8NRx0nHUydBMcEWLpStqZSZpqSRrQOh7Ax1ChKLS1INNBSzdQ11gISRpo6Tpo6jpmZxaRLQQA1FT6ARnppQwzWUHJV0FJScgISxtqEmF1zUyRkk7uLqBqQMDYBS/wE)...

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 42 bytes

```
≔⁻ＮＬζθ≔⁰εＷ¬‹θ⁰«Ｆ¬＆ε⊗ε≧⁻⁺Ｌζ∧﹪ε²Ｌηθ≦⊕ε»§⁺ηζθ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY/dagIxEIWvzVPM5QRSkKKl4NVurT/givQN1t3pJhATzU8tFp89Zt3W3p1hzjnzTSNr19hap1R4rzqDlTLR49ocY9jGw54ccgEbMl2QeOFZn/iM/XrHAihPZ6k0AW5twA15jycBY845/LDRp3XDolThrDwVpkUSMLdxrylL3vuq@jgUfqhOhoFAwE5njsdhAX20sm3Utm94/qeS/A9r9GjKDzSODmQCtQPkle2cMgGLsDYtfeO9Xgq43LN8ltJk@voyZcVbWbL5@2K5Sk9f@gY) Link is to verbose version of code. Takes the index as the first input. Explanation: I wanted to avoid building up a humunguous string but the code is still slow because I don't know a good way of calculating Fibbinary numbers.

```
≔⁻ＮＬζθ
```

Subtract the length of `B` from `n`.

```
≔⁰ε
```

Start enumerating Fibbinary numbers.

```
Ｗ¬‹θ⁰«
```

Repeat until `n` is negative.

```
Ｆ¬＆ε⊗ε
```

Is the current index a Fibbinary number?

```
≧⁻⁺Ｌζ∧﹪ε²Ｌηθ
```

If so then subtract the length of either `B` or `BA` from `n` depending on whether the current index is even or odd.

```
≦⊕ε
```

Increment the index.

```
»§⁺ηζθ
```

Output the `n`th character of `AB` (since `n` is negative here, Charcoal counts back from the end).

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>76</s> 66 bytes

*Edit: -10 bytes thanks to Giuseppe*

```r
f=function(b,a,n)`if`(nchar(b)>n,substr(b,n,n),f(paste0(b,a),b,n))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bYwxDsIwDEX3nqISg2PhoRUUsbRXoXGIaRaDmvT8IZFQu7B9/ff01iyBH26x65hllE1dCm81TJYU5yCz0QoN46QUN46pbNICSczHxuS7KiOVE3GPGXh6eS1AYB0z0HW434Zzj@2pBYbm0LgqQJd/rCQqZQfUdz/BQ5O/)

Recursive function: input the starting strings `b` and `a` (note reversed order), and the 1-based index to output.

Could be a bit shorter ([53 bytes](https://tio.run/##bYzNCsIwDMfve4qBhzaYg0MnXuaLyHBNbdaCRBjz@btYpCB4@EHy/1oyJ7r76JYh88Bv8Wt6iSV0KDAlnuwzyLxGS3AVpJuMyNZ/fEDSCNS@quZh0ASFlVmJBlBlp6dXqAB46i/nft9Bu2v1b@pCCWj4@Mf7Wa@rVJYBu8O3EkyTNw)) if inputs are vectors of characters instead of strings.

---

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 48 bytes

```r
function(a,b)repeat{c=b;cat(b<-paste0(b,a));a=c}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TcsxDoAgDAXQ47RNMHFHzmJ@GzQsSKBOxrPj6ttfn0fRfXgv9UzzuKt5uSojqPTcMvyxpNHgrNvSMDyvrAEiEcneX2YCBVKS@QE)

Prints the infinite string.

Comment: Take `b` and `a` separately for [66 bytes](https://tio.run/##bYwxDsIwDEX3nqISg2PhoRUUsbRXoXGIaRaDmvT8IZFQu7B9/ff01iyBH26x65hllE1dCm81TJYU5yCz0QoN46QUN46pbNICSczHxuS7KiOVE3GPGXh6eS1AYB0z0HW434Zzj@2pBYbm0LgqQJd/rCQqZQfUdz/BQ5O/)

Comment: @Giuseppe - Oh, for goodness sake!  That's so obvious now you've suggested it!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 63 bytes

```powershell
param($x,$y,$n)$a=$x,$y
1..$n|%{$a+=$a[$_]+$a[$_-1]}
$a[-1][$n]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/vyCxKDFXQ6VCR6VSRyVPUyXRFszmMtTTU8mrUa1WSdS2VUmMVomP1QZTuoaxtVxAFpCOVsmL/f//v6OT838XV7f/hgYA)

-11 bytes thanks to julian

Comment: [63 bytes?](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/vyCxKDFXQ6VCR6VSRyVPUyXRFszmMtTTU8mrUa1WSdS2VUmMVomP1QZTuoaxtVxAFpCOVsmL/f//v6OT838XV7f/hgYA "PowerShell – Try It Online")

Comment: "You may choose any format for the input." - [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/vyCxKDFXQyVRRyVP01BPTyWvRrVaJVHbViUxWiU@VhtM6RrG1nIBWUA6WiUv9v///45Ozjourm7/DQ0A "PowerShell – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 70 bytes

```java
(a,b,n)->{for(var t=a;b.length()<=n;a=b,b=t)t=b+a;return b.charAt(n);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hY4xT8MwEIX3/opTJlu4EQiKkIKRmkJhgKlSF8Rwdu3UJXUq5xIJRfntwQldUae74X3vewdscX7YfQ@6xLqGD3QeuhmA82SCRW1gi8GhKs278QXt105VHrV20IHeYwDLNhScLwAFnD8lRhw8z6CPVadGlU5DTUjxtJXbwTFqztznF2Aoaj5Z4V@blQNDoYTn86fOVoG10U0SM5WWU5TxR@kzlEooSZykusIsGGqCB5WOS5fE4qJ@yCbP5qcmc0yrhtJTnEGlZza1LFmu8jwRkDy/rF/f4nO3eLhfcH4BGokRu72YzFfn9nhurv/i/awffgE)